# Сравнить каждый из элементов массивов между собой

Tags: javascript

Есть некий массив. В JavaScript он выглядит так:

```
let array = [["", "", ""], ["", "", "string"], [false, "", ""]];
```

Чтобы упростить объяснение, этот же массив:

```
["", "", ""]
["", "", "string"]
[false, "", ""]
```

**Моя задача:** сравнить все первые, вторые и третье элементы массивов между собой с условиями:

- Если все элементы массива идентичны друг-другу(например, `""`), то вернуть `""`
- Если 2 элемента массива равны `""`, но хоть один равен `false`, то вернуть `false`
- Если 2 элемента массива равны `""`, но хоть один равен `"string"`(или просто строка с `.length > 0`), то вернуть `"string"`

Если наглядно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом, в массиве не обязательно должны быть именно массивы с длинной в 3 индекса. Их может быть от 1 до 6.

У меня была идея, как это можно реализовать:

- Создать динамический массив, наполнить его пустыми массивами(в зависимости от длины `array`)
- Пройтись по каждому нулевому, первому, второму и т.д. индексу и наполнить вложенные в динамический массив массивы значениями, а там уже сверять их между собой.

На второй пункт мне не хватает ни знаний, ни опыта. Как мне реализовать нужный мне алгоритм. В частности, как мне пройтись итератором по нулевым, первым, вторым и т.д. элементам массивов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое что пришло в голову:

```js
const array = [
    [ '', '', '', 'Строка' ],
    [ '', '', 'string', '' ],
    [ false, '', '', '' ]
  ],
  sortArr = [],
  finalArr = [];

/*
* Заполняем промежуточный массив подмассивами состоящими из значений
* подмассивов исходного массива с одинаковыми индексами (запутался пока писал)
*/
for(const arr of array) {
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sortArr[i] = sortArr[i] || [];
    sortArr[i].push(arr[i]);
  }
}

/*
* Просто проверяем условия и формируем финальный результат
*/
for(const sort of sortArr) {
  const sortLength = sort.length;

  for(let i = 0; i < sortLength; i++) {
    const item = sort[i];
    
    if(item === false || (typeof item === 'string' && item.length > 0)) {
      finalArr.push(item);
      break;
    } else if(i + 1 === sortLength) {
      finalArr.push(item);
    }
  }
}

console.log(finalArr);
```

Comment: А если у меня строка динамическая? То есть, необязательно `'string'`.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin, тогда без вложенного перебора не обойтись, обновил ответ.

Comment: Да, до меня уже дошло :) Я сделал так - сперва проверяю, если длина первого элемента равна 0 и все последующие элементы идентичны, то делаю пуш пустой строки. Иначе, запускаю вложенный цикл и при первом встречном boolean или string сразу пушу его в массив с брейком вложенного цикла. https://pastebin.com/0BkjMmYx

Comment: Верна ли моя реализация?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin, хм, я даже метода такого найти не могу) Я бы скорее всего использовал вместо первого условия `if(sort.every(item => item === ''))`. Но в любом случае ваш вариант по идее будет чуть медленнее, так как вы сначала циклом проходитесь по всем массивам, то есть первое условие у вас уже породит 9 итераций, потом все циклы по новой и там будет ещё n'ное кол-во итераций, в моем же варианте итераций будет не больше 9.

Comment: `isAllValuesEqual()` - https://pastebin.com/PBPzyDMM

Comment: Спасибо за замечания по коду :)

Answer (score 0):

> сравнить все первые, вторые и третье элементы ... 
>   в массиве не обязательно должны быть именно массивы с длинной в 3 индекса

Я понял так, что при любом размере вложенных массивов, проверять надо только первые три элемента.

```js
let array = [
  ['', '', '', 'abc'],
  ['', '', 'something'],
  [false, '', '', 'def', 'jhi'],
  ['', '', '', false],
];

let result = array.map(a => {
  let len = Math.max(...(a.slice(0, 3).map(el => el.length)));
  return isNaN(len) ? false : (len > 0 ? 'string' : '');
});
console.log(result);
```

P.S.

> Если все элементы массива идентичны друг-другу

Этот момент не учел сразу

```js
let array = [
  ['a', 'a', 'a', 'abc'],
  ['', '', 'something'],
  [false, '', '', 'def', 'jhi'],
  ['', '', '', false],
];

let result = array.map(a => {
  let len = Math.max(...(a.slice(0, 3).map(el => el.length)));
  return isNaN(len) ? false :
    (len === 0 || (a.slice(0, 3).every((v, i, arr) => v == arr[0])) ?
      '' : 'string');
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: вроде бы автор хочет сравнивать элементы не в одном массиве (строке), а по сути - по столбцам

Comment: @Grundy да, именно так.

Comment: @Grundy, ваша правда, не правильно понял вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Проанализировав условие и тествовый массив, пришёл к выводу, что следует изменить структуру вводных данных. Далее будет проще сделать итерацию. Данный метод работает с **неравными по длинне массивами**.

```
function comparator(arrCompare) {
  'use strict';

  if (!arrCompare || !(Array.isArray(arrCompare)) || !arrCompare.length) { return; }

  // Getting max possible length
  var maxLength = arrCompare.reduce(function(pVal, val) {
    return pVal > val.length ? pVal : val.length;
  }, 0);

  // For new structure
  var correctModel = [],
    i, j;

  // Changing structure
  for (i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
    correctModel.push([]);

    for (j = 0; j < arrCompare.length; j++) {
      if (arrCompare[j][i] !== undefined) {
        correctModel[i].push(arrCompare[j][i]);
      }
    }
  }

  // Comparing 
  return correctModel.map(function (arr, arrInd) {
    return arr.reduce(function (pVal, val, valInd) {
      return (
        pVal === undefined ||
        pVal === false && val.constructor === String && val.length ||
        pVal.constructor === String &&
        !pVal.length &&
        (val.constructor === String && val.length || val === false)
      ) ? val : pVal;
    }, undefined);
  });
}
```